# Create Text File in Memory and return it over ajax, possible?

Tags: asp.net

I can create a text file easily enough but I want to avoid having to keep the file on the server.

How can I create a text file in memory and return it over ajax so the file itself is returned and no file is kept on server? It doesn't need to be ajax but I want to avoid a postback if at all possible.

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: Sorry, using Webforms so using WebMethods for Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to download text file in webforms

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);
tw.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!");
tw.WriteLine("I WANT TO SAVE THIS FILE AS A .TXT FILE!");
tw.Flush();
var bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.txt");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Comment: Only issue I have now is this won't work in ajax (to my knowledge anyway).  I have a list of items on screen which is all jQuery/knockout style code that I need to get id from knockout and download file but I'm struggling to pass the id.  I created a asp:hiddenfield and changed the value using js but the value was alyways 0.

Comment: As suggested by Kamyar you can use `HttpHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Vijay's answer is correct if you're using either MVC or WebForms.

About preventing postback, You don't have to use ajax to prevent postback.

If you're using MVC, You just have to use `window.location` and point it to your action method in js. Something like:

```
// In your controller:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public FileResult GetFile2(int id)
    {
        if (SomeCondition)
        {
           return null;
        }
        var fileName = "MyResult.txt";
        var content = "Here's the result";
        var contentType = "text/plain";
        return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content), contentType, fileName);
   }

// And in your view/js file:
window.location.href = ('/Home/GetFile?id=1');
```

And if you're using webforms, I think best way is to create a `HttpHandler` to handle download links. A good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/122/Simple-File-Download-Protection-with-ASP.NET).